# upload a file using ng-file-upload and send it to Flask

Tags: python, angularjs, flask

I am trying to use [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) in my Flask app, but I'm having a hard time send it to Flask `main.py` to be saved.  I could have just done a simple submit using flask's `url_for()`, but I would like to keep Flask in the backend and AngularJS in the front-end.

Also, I would like to use the drag and drop field feature from this angular plugin instead of an upload file button, but I think that's where my issue is coming from.  I don't think flask is recognizing it from `request.files`.  I'm not sure if I'm calling correctly or maybe is just a simple fix and I'm not seeing it.

Flask main.py

```
@app.route("/", methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def index():

if request.method == 'POST':
    print 'unknown went through'
    filestorage = request.files['user_file']
    print filestorage
    if not filestorage:
        return jsonify(fileStatus = False)

    if filestorage.filename.endswith('.xlsx'):
        print "you uploaded a excel file"
        file_new_name = 'dataexcel.xlsx'
        file_type = 'excel'

    elif filestorage.filename.endswith('.csv'):
        print "you uploaded a csv file"
        file_new_name = 'datacsv.csv'
        file_type = 'csv'

    path = "static/uploads/" + file_new_name


    if os.path.exists(path):
        print 'i exist'
        os.remove(path)
        filename = docs.save(filestorage, None, file_new_name)

    else:
        print "i don't exist"
        filename = docs.save(filestorage, None, file_new_name)


    session['path'] = path
    session['file_type'] = file_type

    return jsonify(fileStatus = True)
```

I know the "POST" works because i can see the message from this print statement, `print 'unknown went through'`, after that it fails to recognize the `filestorage` variable

Here is my angular controller:

```
myApp.controller('UploadFileCtrl',[
'$scope',
'$http',
'Upload',
 function($scope, $http, Upload){



// upload later on form submit or something similar
$scope.submit = function(files) {
  if ($scope.files) {
    $scope.upload($scope.files);
  }
}

// upload on file select or drop
$scope.upload = function (files) {
  console.log('it was uploaded');
    Upload.upload({
        url: '/',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {file: files}

    }).then(function (resp) {
        // console.log('Success ' + resp.config.data.file.name + 'uploaded. Response: ' + resp.data);
        console.log(resp.data);
    }, function (resp) {
        console.log('Error status: ' + resp.status);
        console.log(resp);
    }, function (evt) {
        var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
        console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.data.file.name);
    });
}

}])
```

html form:

```
<form ng-click="submit(files)">
<div ngf-drop ngf-select ng-model="files" class="drop-box"
    ngf-drag-over-class="'dragover'" ngf-multiple="true" ngf-allow-dir="true"
  name="user_file" type="file">Drop pdfs or images here or click to upload</div>
<div ngf-no-file-drop>File Drag/Drop is not supported for this browser</div>

<button type="submit">submit</button>
```

I'm still not familiar with Flask, but it's a cool webframework to work with and it will be awesome to integrate it with AngularJS.  Your help will be appreciated, thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

I actually got it to upload in Flask, I need it to replace `filestorage = request.files['user_file']` with `filestorage = request.files['file']`.  Like I said, Flask was not recognizing it by it's provided name in the html, which I don't know why.  I failed to provide this line `return render_template('index.html')` in the main.py above.  Since Flask is not longer present in the html, could that be the reason Flask is not recognizing the `name` in the form?

revised main.py

```
@app.route("/", methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def index():

if request.method == 'POST':
  print 'unknown went through'
  filestorage = request.files['file']
  print filestorage
  if not filestorage:
    return jsonify(fileStatus = False)

  if filestorage.filename.endswith('.xlsx'):
    print "you uploaded a excel file"
    file_new_name = 'dataexcel.xlsx'
    file_type = 'excel'

  elif filestorage.filename.endswith('.csv'):
    print "you uploaded a csv file"
    file_new_name = 'datacsv.csv'
    file_type = 'csv'

  path = "static/uploads/" + file_new_name


  if os.path.exists(path):
    print 'i exist'
    os.remove(path)
    filename = docs.save(filestorage, None, file_new_name)

  else:
    print "i don't exist"
    filename = docs.save(filestorage, None, file_new_name)


  session['path'] = path
  session['file_type'] = file_type

  return jsonify(fileStatus = True)
return render_template('index.html')
```

Also I had to change in the html the `ngf-multiple` to `false`, this was sending an array, so Flask was expecting a dict.

revised html:

```
<form ng-click="submit(files)">
<div ngf-drop ngf-select ng-model="files" class="drop-box"
ngf-drag-over-class="'dragover'" ngf-multiple="true" ngf-allow-dir="true" name="user_file" type="file">Drop pdfs or images here or click to upload</div>
<div ngf-no-file-drop>File Drag/Drop is not supported for this browser</div>

<button type="submit">submit</button>
```

Comment: try printing just `request.files`  maybe also print `request.form`? if you can run your script via a debugger and put   a breakpoint where you are printing your unknown thing ... this(probably) has too many dependencies for someone to reproduce it for you ... so its going to take some extra leg work on your part to properly describe the problem and as much of a diagnostic as you can ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley by printing `request.files`, i get dictionary, this is the output `ImmutableMultiDict([('file[0]', <FileStorage: u'charToTest.xlsx' ('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')>)])`, how do you get access to it? i tried to do something like `if file in request.files`